# C# Registry Subkey dword value

Tags: c#, set, registry, dword

Im making a program that sees if a subkey in Registry exist and, if it doesnt exist it will create a subkey with a value (dword). This program is being create to replace a .bat file that people (non programmers) had to run to execute the .reg file in order to the things i listed above, witch isnt verry appealing for the user, thats why im making this program.

The .reg file sets the keys i want to set as dword, but the value has a 'c' in the end (this is what it looks like):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:0000000c
```

and my c# code looks like this:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(Globais.subkeyWU + @"\AU");
rk.SetValue("ScheduledInstallTime", 0000000c, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

The problem is that the .SetValue function doesnt accept the c in the end of the value, my guess is that it can only be numbers since its a dwrod (not sure), so, annyone knows how do i, bsaicly, do the same thing the .reg file is doing? maybe is hex values, something i dont know how to make in C#...

annyway, here is a printscreen on how it looks in the regedit (the .reg file does this):

[image]

Regardless, thanks!

Comment: c == hexadecimal value. Try 0x0000000c or 12.

Comment: I feel a little dumb right now ahaha. Thanks it worked!

Comment: `DWORD` is a double `WORD` and `WORD` is basically 2 bytes ( 16bits ).  As you can see `DWORD` will be 4 bytes ( 32 bits ) wide value which corresponds with `int`. To set this to `0000000c` just place `12` in the second parameter.

Comment: Much appreciated! It makes sence now"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading the comments in my post, I can awnser my own question!

The solution to my problem is:

```
rk.SetValue("ScheduledInstallTime", 0x0000000c, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

or

```
rk.SetValue("ScheduledInstallTime", 12, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Because im trying to store a hexadecimal value in the registry, i either translate it do decimal or type the full hexadecimal value, like i did above.

Thanks for the comments, really made me understand and solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Replace **0000000c** by **12**

```
rk.SetValue("ScheduledInstallTime", 12, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```